# issue in importing from innodb to ndbcluster

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a table with lots of columns. We are trying to import into MySQL 7.3 cluster. But we get the following error everytime: "Got Error 708 no more attribute meta data records increase max no of attributes ndbcluster"

Our config.ini is as follows:

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
BackupMaxWriteSize=1M
BackupDataBufferSize=16M
BackupLogBufferSize=4M
BackupMemory=20M
BackupReportFrequency=10
MemReportFrequency=30
LogLevelStartup=15
LogLevelShutdown=15
LogLevelCheckpoint=8
LogLevelNodeRestart=15
DataMemory=2247M
IndexMemory=374M
MaxNoOfTables=4096
MaxNoOfTriggers=3500
NoOfReplicas=2
StringMemory=25
DiskPageBufferMemory=64M
SharedGlobalMemory=20M
LongMessageBuffer=32M
MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions=16384
BatchSizePerLocalScan=512
FragmentLogFileSize=256M
NoOfFragmentLogFiles=13
RedoBuffer=32M
MaxNoOfExecutionThreads=2
StopOnError=false
LockPagesInMainMemory=1
TimeBetweenEpochsTimeout=32000
TimeBetweenWatchdogCheckInitial=60000
TransactionInactiveTimeout=60000
HeartbeatIntervalDbDb=1500
HeartbeatIntervalDbApi=1500
MaxNoOfAttributes=4G



[NDBD]
NodeId=1
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir=D:/MySQL_Cluster/1/
MaxNoOfAttributes=4G
MaxNoOfTables=4096


[NDBD]
NodeId=2
HostName=127.0.0.1
DataDir=D:/MySQL_Cluster/2/
MaxNoOfAttributes=4G
MaxNoOfTables=4096
```

Please suggest how to import a big table

Answer (score 0):

4G is bigger than the limit mentioned in the manual:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnoofattributes